# Method containing interface as parameter

Tags: java, interface

hello how do I call a method taking an interface as a parameter from the main ?
The code in the main is an example of what I want to achieve but by calling the method map now

What do I write in my map method and how do I call it in the main ? Thank you

What I want to achieve :

```
StringTransformation addBlah = (e) -> {
    e += "boo";
     return e;
};
System.out.println(addBlah.transf("Hello")); // prints Helloboo
```

---

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = hello;
        // How do I modify the string a by calling map ?


    }

    void map(StringTransformation t) {
        // What do I write ??
    }
}

public interface StringTransformation {
    String transf(String s);
}
```

Comment: With out the interface definition it's hard to say.  Please include the code for the interface.

Comment: You pass an instance of a class that has implemented said interface.

Comment: @markspace Sorry I forgot, I added it now

Comment: Also, unless I missed something, `map` will need to be `static` to be called from `main`.

Comment: Aside: you can simply use `e -> e += "boo"` as your lambda declaration. No need for braces or return, since `a += b` is an expression.

Comment: What is the class which includes the main method ? Please add top definition

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry, I wasn't clear enough I edited my post. What I want is to achieve the same result as my lambda expression but by doing it through the map method. I have a string then when I call the method map it will modify the string

Comment: edited my answer, I think I figured out what you want

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify a `String` with a given `StringTransformation` so you need to pass both of them to the `map` method. Also you can turn `addBlah` in a more simple lambda :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTransformation addBlah = (e) -> e + "boo";

    String str = "Hello";
    System.out.println(str);    // Hello
    str = map(addBlah, str);
    System.out.println(str);    // Helloboo
}

static String map(StringTransformation t, String argument) { 
    return t.transf(argument);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `map` inside the `static` `main` method. You must make `map` a static method as well if you want to do that.  Also we can't help you with what to put inside your `map` function if you don't tell us what it should do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string = "Hello";
    // you can call `mapBoo` like normal here
    string = mapBoo(string);
    System.out.println(string);

    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "this", "is", "a", "test");

    // or you can pass mapBoo into the stream.map method since map fits the method signature
    List<String> mappedStrings = strings.stream().map(Main::mapBoo)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (String mappedString : mappedStrings)
        System.out.println(mappedString);
}


static String mapBoo(String s) {
    return s + "boo";
}
```

Comment: I have a string a = "Hello" initialized in the main class and when I call map from the main  I want it to modify string a to "Helloboo"